# Character literal compile error

Tags: c#

I downloaded a library to handle RTF. It won't compile. It fails on a character literal and I cannot figure out what it is.

The source is posted on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rtfdomparser/). The problem is in RtfNodeGroup.cs and it is at the end of the following code. `myStr.Append( '¨C' );`

When I look at the character sequence using od, it is ASCII '250 C'.

I know that there are two characters in the literal. This is how the code was posted on SourceForge. The block of code above the one in question failed also, but I substituted the literal for emdash as follows:

```
    if( node.Keyword == "emdash")
    {
        AddString( myStr , buffer );
        myStr.Append( '\u2014');
        continue ;
    }
```

What do you think it is?

```
else if( node.Type == RTFNodeType.Control || node.Type == RTFNodeType.Keyword )
{
    if( node.Keyword == "tab" )
    {
        AddString( myStr , buffer );
        myStr.Append( '\t' );
        continue ;
    }

    if( node.Keyword == "emdash")
    {
        AddString( myStr , buffer );
        myStr.Append( '¡ª');
        continue ;
    }

    if( node.Keyword == "" )
    {
        AddString( myStr , buffer );
        myStr.Append( '¨C' );
        continue ;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you can say what is your actual goal? This sounds to be a [XYProblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: In you single quotes there are at least 2 chars.

Comment: My actual goal is to determine what the author meant and substitute the proper character literal to enable the code to compile.

Comment: As @HamletHakobyan said, try to replace each ' by ". ' is for char and " is for string.

Comment: If this is from the actual source code, I would probably look for a different library. I wouldn't be surprised if you end up with other more painful issues down the road after you get it compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're opening the file with the wrong encoding. It seems to be saved in UTF-8, while you're opening it in some form of ASCII+. Try to force the code file to be UTF-8, and it should work fine IMO.

**EDIT**: Okay, I actually downloaded the source and checked, and I believe that it might have been accidentally double encoded. If those are the only issues, just replace the string contents with the proper character (ideally using the `\u2014` notation, which doesn't depend on code file encoding beyond ASCII).

**FINAL EDIT**: The name of the author tipped me off. The file is actually encoded in chinese (mainland) encoding (`windows-936`), not UTF-8. Convert the files to UTF-8 and you should be fine. In the proper encoding, `¡ª` turns to `—` etc. The second one is actually `–`.

Comment: Thanks Luaan. When I do this, the emdash is encoded as '??' and the second literal as '?C'. Searching for these characters results in nothing.

Comment: I've already done the emdash (\u2014) but there's no hint at what the other might be. An empty string? Thanks for taking the time to look at this, Luaan.

Comment: @user1268144 Check my latest edit, the file is actually saved in chinese encoding. Mystery solved :)

Comment: I can't see for sure, but is the second character an en-dash or hyphen?

Comment: @user1268114 I have no idea, I just copied the character as-is. You can copy it the same way into your code file. Or, as I've suggested, use some file encoding tool to convert the files from `windows-936` to `utf-8`.

Comment: It converts to UTF-8 '??' and '?C', which is obviously not a character. I'll go with the dash. In ASCII, the two dashes are \u2013 and \u2014. Thanks for all your effort, Luaan.

Comment: @user1268114 You have to convert it from `windows-936`, otherwise it can't work. Also, just for clarity, `\u2013` is *not* ASCII - that's a unicode character. ASCII only has 7-bit characters.